# Azure Functions Continuous Deployment Failing on Syncing Function Triggers Step

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I have my continuous deployment configured to use Bitbucket and release on a push to master. This has been working perfectly up until today. Now even builds that have previously been successful are failing on the `Syncing Function Triggers` step...

[image]

The final step `Deployment Successful.` doesn't show up. I downloaded the deployment logs and noticed that there is an error on one of the calls to Kudu.

> 2017-11-14T19:06:37.6185924Z,Syncing 3 function triggers with payload size 485 bytes failed with System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Response status code does not indicate success: 500 (Internal Server Error).\r\n   at System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode()\r\n   at Kudu.Core.Helpers.PostDeploymentHelper.d__33.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Kudu.Core.Helpers.PostDeploymentHelper.d__25.MoveNext(),808a1bcf-e2c6-4e71-a5ba-8ba6afbb5c10,0

I can only assume that Kudu updated their API and now something is breaking in azure the deployment configuration. Is there a way to see or edit the Kudu .deploy file to gain more insight?

Comment: Can you check the logs by using verbose in kudu sync.  http://microsoftazurewebsitescheatsheet.info/#deployment   Not sure if the  zip API changes are impacting your changes. http://markheath.net/post/deploy-azure-webapp-kudu-zip-api

Comment: You should bug Alex to help you setup a proper build and release pipeline on VSTS. It's surprisingly easy and gives you way more flexibility for this kind of stuff. PS I miss you :(

Comment: It's a bug, and we're looking into it now. I'll update.

Comment: See also https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-cli/issues/315

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was caused by an issue with the Azure Functions service. The issue has now been resolved, and everything should be working again.

Apologies for the downtime of that sync API.

Comment: Yup I tried this morning and it seems to be back to normal. Thanks :)